# Getting requested entity synonym rather than the reference value

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

When I do app.getArgument("ARGUMENT_NAME") it returns the reference value for synonym. How do I determine the requested synonym rather than the reference value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the JSON, this used to be available in the "result"."parameters"."*name*.original" field, but that seems to have changed at some point.

Now you can find it in the parameters for any of the contexts. So if you are using JavaScript and have the JSON in a variable named "body" and the argument name in a variable named "name", you can probably evaluate something like

```
body.result.contexts[0].parameters[`${name}.original`]
```

to get the value you want.

Comment: Perfect! I was sniffing around https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/DialogflowApp#getContextArgument but wasn't quite there.